# asp.net mvc 5 optional language prefix in routes

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I em using attributes to define routes in my controllers.
What I want to implement is optional language prefix for every defined routes.
For example:

```
Home:
/ or /en-US or /de
User:
/user or /en-US/user or /de/user
Item:
/item or /en-US/item or /de/item
```

If I define routes like this:

```
Home:
{lang?}
User:
{lang?}/user
Item:
{lang?}/item
```

and then I navigate to /user application crashed withe error

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL
```

I also wants to create html helpers like ActionLink, RouteLink etc. witch will generate links without prefix if language is same as default language (default language is defined in application) or links with prefix if language is different than default language. Is there some simple solution for this?

Comment: Have a look in your RouteConfig.cs, there you can define a pattern which part of the url belongs to which type of controller

    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new {lang = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

It's up to you how you will handle the different languages

Comment: I decide to disable default routing configuration and I only use attribute routing so defining routs with routes.MapRute is not acceptable.
Documentation for asp.net mvc 6 says that attribute routing is preferred [ASP.NET 5 DOC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html#recommendations)

Comment: However I resolve this problem with RouteFactoryAttribute and IRouteConstraint. This solution requires to add one more attribute on every controller action so I decide to implement my version of DefaultDirectRouteProvider class and for every route I add one more with language prefix.

Comment: I have one new problem now with owin cookie authentication. My LoginPath is "/login" so if user is not authorized it will be redirected to this path. But I want to redirect user to this path with language prefix. I em trying to override ApplyRedirect method from CookieAuthenticationProvider but I don't know how to extract language prefix from CookieApplyRedirectContext.Request and then change CookieApplyRedirectContext.RedirectUri.